# Spring boot: как указать в .properties тип хранилища данных (MySQL или файл)?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

Добрый день.
Есть приложение на Spring boot и в нем файл    .properties:

```
# Database
spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password: root

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

В приложении нужно использовать сохранение данных либо в БД либо в файл .CSV.
Изменения в .properties вступают в силу только после перезапуска JVM.

Вопрос: как указать в .properties, что данные должны сохраняться или в БД или в файл?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен! Ну а "так" вы всегда можете сделать `my.superpuper.attribute = value` и в коде обработайте как вам угодно!

Comment: Нужно отталкиваться от условия, которое определяет, куда вы сохраняете в БД или CSV. Если какая-то логика в коде, то в properties-файле пропишите все настройки, а для записи в коде создайте фасад и две его реализации и в зависимости от условия используйте ту или другую.